# 141 DPI monitor

Tags: monitors

I have a laptop with a 15.6" 1920x1080 screen. I want to purchase a monitor to
use with this laptop. I use XFCE, it is not possible to specify DPI per monitor
in XFCE. In order to make text on the monitor to be the same size as on the
laptop screen, I want the monitor DPI to be as close as possible to the laptop
screen.

I made some calculations and composed a list of common monitor resolutions and
sizes that would have a DPI close to the needed:

```
|Width|Height|Size (inch)|DPI             |
|-----|------|-----------|----------------|
|2560 |1600  |23.0       |131.255389663396|
|3200 |1600  |27.0       |132.507731999988|
|1920 |1200  |17.0       |133.185615981976|
|2560 |1440  |22.0       |133.509525459533|
|2048 |1536  |19.0       |134.736842105263|
|2560 |1440  |21.5       |136.614398144639|
|2560 |1600  |22.0       |137.221543739005|
|3840 |2160  |32.0       |137.681698130144|
|3440 |1440  |27.0       |138.119846172523|
|2048 |1536  |18.5       |138.378378378378|
|3840 |1600  |30.0       |138.666666666667|
|2560 |1080  |20.0       |138.924439894498|
|2560 |1600  |21.5       |140.41274243061 |
|1920 |1080  |15.6       |141.211998082199|  <- My laptop
|4096 |2160  |32.0       |144.707463525556|
|1920 |1200  |15.6       |145.138171262409|
|2560 |1080  |19.0       |146.236252520524|
|2560 |1440  |20.0       |146.860478005487|
|3840 |2160  |30.0       |146.860478005487|
|3200 |1600  |24.0       |149.071198499986|
|2560 |1080  |18.5       |150.188583669728|
|2048 |1536  |17.0       |150.588235294118|
|2560 |1600  |20.0       |150.943698112906|
```

But I failed to find any existing monitors sold with these parameters. What monitors exist with a DPI as close to 141 as possible?

Comment: The problem with the DPI/PPI you have chosen is that I suspect laptop screens pack pixels more densely than desktop monitors. [This monitor has a DPI of ~= 139.87](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824011158&ignorebbr=1&nm_mc=AFC-C8Junction&cm_mmc=AFC-C8Junction-PCPartPicker,%20LLC-_-na-_-na-_-na&cm_sp=&AID=10446076&PID=3938566&SID=), but unless you're willing to drop $370 on it, it's most likely an un-viable option. It appears that resolutions lower than 4k are most likely going to demand a monitor with a diagonal screen size that smaller than the market provides for it.

Comment: Thank you for the link. 1920x1080 seems to be a common resolution for 15.6" laptop screens, there's nothing specific to the one I chose. The 32" monitor you suggest seems huge, I was hoping to find something within 22-27". It feels weird that there aren't many external screens with the same DPI as in common laptop screens.

Comment: Well I have a 15.6" 4k laptop monitor that has a DPI/PPI of ~= 282.42. If I wanted to find a corresponding 1080p monitor with equivalent DPI, the desktop monitor would only be 7.8 inches wide, and I'd be willing to bet that there is not a single desktop monitor on the market that has as ludicrous a size as that. In fact if I set my DPI scaling to 100%, the fonts/visuals are absolutely puny. It maybe worth trying to do some research into "hacking" XFCE's OS to the DPI scaling you want. That would certainly be more economic.

Comment: I don't know how is your hypothetical tiny 1080p monitor relevant to my question about regular-sized monitors with a specific DPI. Thank you for your input.